# MySQL/PHP: How can we bind a parameter to both (?)s in prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

If this is my code:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "mydb");

    $city = "Some";

    $q = "SELECT District FROM City WHERE (Name=? OR ? IS NULL)";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q)) {

        // How to Bind $city here?
    }
```

How can I bind `$city` to both `?`s?

Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(1, $city);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $city); ?

Comment: did my answer solved your problem or helpful; for you ?

Comment: +1 for your attention Null and thank you. According to my comment to your post, I've wanted another thing.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by

```
$stmt -> bind_param("for first ?", 'for second ?');
```

or try like

```
   /* Bind our params */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $Name, $city);

    /* Set our params */
    $Name= "hello";
    $city= "city";

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();
```

The values can be:

```
i - Integer
d - Decimal
s - String
b - Blob (sent in packets)
```

Comment: I have a function for this that do this process automatically. I don't want to do it manually. So I have to pass $city 2 times to my function? // I have one $city param not 2 parameters like $city AND $name